# Why does my new vscode extention fail to start?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am creating an extention for a DSL. I have followed the instructions about [developing extentions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/developing-extensions), but then when I press F5 to test it, I get an error message Activating extension 'ampersandtarski.language-ampersand' failed:

[this is how the error message looks that I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKAL2.png)

If you'd care to help out, the code of the extention is at [github](https://github.com/AmpersandTarski/Ampersand-Language-Support)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to retrieve the [`LanguageConfiguration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#LanguageConfiguration) with the `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration` command. This command refers to the User or Workspace settings. If you actually want to contribute user settings check out [this docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesconfiguration).

However currently it is **not possible** to get the `LanguageConfiguration`. The corresponding feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2871).